# Audio assets not found in Vue/Webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js

([See fiddle](https://github.com/ripper234/ogg-webpacket-asset-fiddle)  forked from webpack vue-cli sampple)

Why are image assets successfully bundled by webpack, but audio assets aren't?
(I'm using a project derived from the vue-cli webpack project)

When I write

```
<img src="../assets/logo.png"></img>
<audio src="../assets/ding.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
```

the logo is rendered just fine, but I get a 404 for the ding.ogg audio file.

Comment: I think you have to modify your webpack.config file - so idea is set file loader to recognize the .ogg files `loaders: [{
          test: /\.(ogg|mp4)$/,
          loader: 'file'
        }]`.Assuming you have file-loader installed

Comment: I added it, still no good. Check out this fiddle: https://github.com/ripper234/ogg-webpacket-asset-fiddle

Comment: Hm if you try with `url` loader instead of `file` ?

Comment: Yeah, tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The **audio** tag with **src** attribute is not processed by vue-loader by default:

To add more tag+attribute you can use **transformToRequire** value on the options of the vue-loader:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
        // other options...
        transformToRequire: {
            "audio": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is stuck on it yet as I've been for several days before. My solution is

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          // other options...
          audio: 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

See more details about `transformAssetUrls` -- https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to do this through `vue.config.js`?